# Django ImageField url incorrect in admin view

Tags: django, media

I have a model that stores an image in a media subdirectory, "media/games/".  The image uploads to the correct location but when I try to retrieve it in the admin page it's trying to retrieve it in the base media/ path, and doesn't seem to  reach down into the games folder, so that if I look under:

> localhost:8000/media/games/image.png

it will show the image, but if I am in admin and click on the image link for the preview it tries to find it at:

> localhost:8000/media/image.png

Shouldn't the ImageField be "games/image.png" instead of just "image.png"?  I don't think the image field is storing the path correctly.

Here are my files:

MODELS:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

fs = FileSystemStorage(location="media/games/")

    class Game(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=127, unique=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=127, unique=True)
        summary = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
        description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
        release_date = models.DateField('date released', null=True, blank=True)
        released = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        purchase_link = models.URLField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        card_image = models.ImageField(storage=fs, null=True, blank=True)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.title)
```

URLS:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from InvenTorrey.settings import base
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from games import urls as game_urls



urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^^api/v1/', include(game_urls)),
]

if base.DEBUG is True:
    urlpatterns += static(base.MEDIA_URL, document_root=base.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

SETTINGS:

```
BASE_DIR = 
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static/")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `storage` argument try to use `upload_to`:

```
card_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='games/', null=True, blank=True)
```

This allows you to save images to `media/games/` directory, and also will add `games/` to image's url path.

Comment: just figured it out as I saw this come through.  works perfect, thanks.  will approve as soon as it lets me